# Devise Suspendable gem failure due to reliance to Activatable module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I get the following error trying to use the [devise_suspendable](https://github.com/amolk/devise_suspendable) gem.

```
/home/graeme/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@epra/gems/devise-1.4.5/lib/devise/models.rb:60:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::Activatable (NameError)
```

It's trying to use the activatable module in Devise but I have a feeling it's been deprecrated.

I've tried running with the suspendable module included, but ignoring the activatable module. I don't get any errors, but it doesn't stop a suspended user from logging in either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found a solution for this problem exactly, it turns out to be quite easy to use the lockable module in Devise instead.